# Use MacBook Pro airport for injection with kismac

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, macbook

I want use [kismac](http://trac.kismac-ng.org/) to break my WEP wireless password with my MacBook Pro, but when I go to the step that want to inject packets it's doesn't do anything! I some where read that MacBook Pro wireless cards didn't support injection! Is that right?

How can I solve this? If I must buy USB Wireless Modem which one is better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The wireless chipset used in the MBP **does not** support packet injection. It is not something that can be enabled or anything like that. You need to buy an external card that has a chipset that does support packet injection.

Also, you can crack a password with kismac if you let it read enough packets on the network also.  There is a menu with a couple different methods of doing this.  It takes some time, but it does work.  It is amazing how fast it can figure some out. Packet injection will spend up this process greatly, but isn't completely needed if you got the time to listen to the network.

This is the card I bought that I have read has os x compatibility and an injection capable chipset.  I have not spent a ton of time with it yet though. Been a good little card so far and cheap.
[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833166022&cm_re=roswill_usb_wireless-*-33-166-022-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833166022&cm_re=roswill_usb_wireless-_-33-166-022-_-Product)

I also liked that card for the removable external antenna. I had a 7dbi I wanted to use and this card fit the bill nicely.

Comment: can you suggest some low cost and good performance one?

Comment: Yah, I added the card I got.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. My 2007 MPB fully supports packet injection in backtrack. The OS X drivers don't I think, but the chipset itself does.

Comment: Do newer MBP's, like a 2016 one, support packet injection? I've had some luck with packet injection through bettercap on Linux with my mac, but most of the time it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Kismac Hardware list 
( Can not post more than one hyperlink) just add the h...
trac.kismac-ng.org/wiki/HardwareList

Recommended by the Kismac team: 
ALFA AWUS036s
PS: Read the FAQ, the RFAQ, Repeat. 
PS2: CHECK THE CHIPSET AND FCC NUMBER BEFORE YOU BUY.  (repeat that sentence in your head 999 times)

Kismac 101 Video (a good one)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pyiz2Mct6dk

Edit: If you wonder why I mention to read the FAQ and check the FCC number is because the Kismac Forum is full of people that purchased a 1) non supported USB 2) purchased a knock off or a USB where the manufacturer had silently changed the chipset. the FCC number is one of the best guarantee that the chipset is correct. Do some due diligence before buying and you'll save a lot of time, money and/or trouble. I would advise you to buy from a brick and mortar shop if you can. At least you can return the USB at no fees if not working.

Kismac Airport Extreme: The more active is the network, the faster you'll collect IV's. That simple. Nota Bene: Airport Extreme in Passive mode is stealth, Dehauth, Flood, are not. It may and will reveal your attack. Console Log keep traces of that.